# Managing scheduled tasks

Tags: wp-cron

I want users of my plugin to be able to define whether a task operates daily, twice daily, hourly or not at all as per the standard WP set-up.  I'm storing these as 'daily', 'twicedaily', 'hourly' or '' in the option obr_scheduled_interval.

The problem is that the task that I want 'obr_grab' runs every time there's a page visit rather than every time there's a page visit after the selected time period.

These are the relevant bits of code from the class.

```
function __construct(){
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array(&$this, 'obr_activate_scheduled_task'));
    add_action('obr_scheduled_task', array(&$this, 'obr_activate_scheduled_task'));
    add_shortcode('obr_grab', array(&$this, 'obr_grab'));
    register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, array(&$this, 'obr_deactivate_scheduled_task'));
}

function obr_activate_scheduled_task() {
    // function to activate the scheduled task (if there is one);
    if (wp_next_scheduled('obr_scheduled_task')){
        wp_clear_scheduled_hook('obr_scheduled_task');
    }
    $interval = get_option('obr_scheduled_interval');
    if (strlen($interval) > 0){
        wp_schedule_event(time(), $interval, 'obr_scheduled_task');
    }
}

function obr_scheduled_task(){
    // if called we need to use the grab function
    $this->obr_grab();
}

function obr_deactivate_scheduled_task(){
    // clear the schedule on deactivation
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('obr_scheduled_task');
}
```

I've looked at [core control](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/core-control/screenshots/) but there are only two standard jobs there: wp_scheduled_auto_draft_delete and wp_scheduled_delete

All help much appreciated!

Comment: Small hint for debugging: Use the plugin "Debug Objects" and you see all crons.

Comment: Thank you.  It shows up that there are 2 standard jobs, as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that this line

```
add_action('obr_scheduled_task', array(&$this, 'obr_activate_scheduled_task'));
```

should be

```
add_action('obr_scheduled_task', array(&$this, 'obr_scheduled_task'));
```

otherwise you are re-scheduling on every page visit.

**Edit:**

Here is a logger that can be useful when debugging wp-cron:

```
function my_logger($var){
    $logfile="/tmp/logger.txt"; // EDIT this to your needs
    file_put_contents($logfile, date("Y-m-d: H:i:s",time())." --- ".print_r($var, true)."\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

You can use it inside your class functions with relevant debug messages,

```
 my_logger("My Class construction");
 my_logger("Running the cron function");
```

and the logfile will look like this:

```
2013-02-20: 14:00:43 --- My Class construction
2013-02-20: 14:00:53 --- Running the cron function
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed that but it's still calling 'obr_grab' on every page.

Comment: did you re-activate the plugin after your changes and are you sure the function is not used elsewhere, like from the shortcode?

Comment: Hi - yes, I did reactivate it and no, the shortcode isn't being used elsewhere.  I'm completely puzzled!!!

Comment: I tried your code and it is not running on every page visit on my install - I also used the logger function I added above to watch it.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting.  Many thanks for the logger function.  I was running the plugin on a multisite version of WP so I've just tried it on a fresh install and it's okay!?!

Comment: It is a multisite thing!  I've just created a new site and installed the plugin and it's triggering the "grab"!

Comment: great its working for you ;-) (I tested it on a single user install)

Comment: Did anyone figure out why it doesn't work on Multisite?